# How can I enter text on my Sony Alpha 77 ii?

Tags: sony-alpha

I want to set my wireless access point on my Sony Alpha 77 ii. I can select my network alright, but then it asks to input the password. I know the password, that's not the problem. It's just that I don't know how to enter the text. (My camera came without a keyboard.)

PS: I checked the user manual, it doesn't say: *"Press [dot] in the center of the multi-selector and enter the password if a key icon is displayed with a wireless access point, then select [OK]."*

Comment: How does the *User Manual* tell you to enter the password?

Comment: Manual says: "Press [dot] in the center of the multi-selector
and enter the password if a key icon is displayed with a
wireless access point, then select [OK]."

Comment: what happens when you press dot? i'd assume you get to select each character by scrolling up/down or the like.

Answer (score 3):

From Section 235 of the *[ILCA-77M2 Help Guide](http://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1410/v1/en/print.pdf)*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The support page for your camera that includes several other resources can be accessed at https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=ILCA77M2&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=manuals#/manualsTab